# What is the mechanism of iterator numerically in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Can you please explain the mechanism of iterator for finding maximum number and finding number in the following code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#define n 3

using namespace std;
class student{
public:
    void vrod();
    void dis();
    int stno,score,i;
    string name;
};


int main(){
    int l,*find_score;
   vector<student> my_vector;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        student new_student;

        cout << "Number: ";
        cin >> new_student.stno;
        cout << "Score: ";
        cin >> new_student.score;
       cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> new_student.name;

        my_vector.push_back(new_student);
    }

int max_score = std::max_element(
    my_vector.begin(),
    my_vector.end(),
    [] (student const& lhs, student const& rhs){
        return lhs.score < rhs.score;

    }
)->score;
cout<<max_score;
cout<<"l=";
cin>>l;
auto iter = std::find_if(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(),
                      [l] (student const& scores){ return scores.score ==l; });


if ( iter != my_vector.end())
      cout<<"it is available"<<(*iter).name<<(*iter).stno;
else
      cout<<"not available";

cin.get();
cin.get();
}
```

You suppose that I enter number, score and name respectively as below:

```
1 3    sam
2 3.5  larry
3 3.75 john
```

I want to know which numbers will be in place of max_score,lhs,rhs,my_vector.begin(),my_vector.end(),**iter** and ***iter** and how do max_element and find_if work and replace numbers basically numerically?
Many Thanks beforehand,

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: Yes. I run the program and there is no problem, but I do not know how it is going.

Comment: And, where did I imply that it doesn't work? Debugger will let you inspect the values of the variables, at varying steps of execution.

Comment: `student.score` and `max_score` should be `float`s to store values such as 3.75 unless you want to store 375 and divide (by 100.0) later. What's `student.i` for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, I recommend looking for online reference before asking questions about how a `std` function works. Follow links to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) to find out how they can be implemented.

[`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) finds the biggest element in the range of iterators passed to it. When also passed in a function, it will use the function instead of `operator<` for comparison. In your case, it returns an iterator to the student with the maximum score.

[`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns the first element that satisfies the predicate supplied. In your case, it returns the first student that has `score == l`.

Also, iterators do not replace their content. A iterator is merely a pointer to its underlying element.

For the sake of answering your question:

```
max_score = 3.75 // Note this is impossible because score is int
lhs and rhs students that are compared, and would depend on the implementation of max_element
    Suppose max_element has a max_itr internally, one possibility is:

    max_itr points to Sam at first
    Then, lhr is Sam and rhs is Larry, comparison returns true. max_itr points to Larry.
    Then, lhr is Larry and rhs is John, comparison returns true. max_itr points to John.
    max_itr == end, return max_itr

my_vector.begin() returns an iterator pointing to Sam
my_vector.end()   returns an iterator pointing to the end of vector, a non-existing element
iter              is an iterator pointing to John (Because his score is equal to max_score)
iter*             is John as student&
```

Comment: I don't have good reading materials on iterators at the moment. [This page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) may be helpful if you think of a pointer to an array as an array iterator.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I do not have any problem with definition of pointer.int=*p,m,s;
m=5;
p=&m;
s=*p;
But, in these programs we are using only * without defining & as address. Why? I cannot understand this matter!?

Comment: Iterators define their `operator*` to provide pointer like interface. The address they point to is defined when they are created. For `vector`, `begin()` and `end()` creates iterators, and very likely uses & in their function body to take address.

Comment: Also note that iterator may not behave exactly like a pointer. An iterator for `set` has `operator++` that points the iterator to the next element in a binary search tree, instead of simply incrementing address. This is a kind of encapsulation that allow programmers focus on high-level concepts (that we are getting the next element) without worrying about implementation detail (how to find the next element in the tree).

Comment: It is written that pointers are usable for low-level programs. So, is using pointers in object-oriented programs common?

Comment: On one hand, pointers in C++ enables virtual function calls, on top of its basic utility. So it can be argued that pointers are the building blocks of OOP in C++. On the other hand, manual memory management may be underwhelming in certain situations. So people invented `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` to provide additional functionality on top of raw pointers. It is totally OK to use raw pointers in OOP, but you should also know that there are better alternatives depending on the problem at hand.

Comment: To be honest though, when you work on very high-level concepts, there will be no need to worry about pointers. They become part of "implementation detail". You may not even know you are using pointers!

Comment: Thanks for helps. I have two more questions.1) we write if ( iter != my_vector.end()). In this way John has the maximum score as the last person, although we write if iter!=my_vector.end(). So in this way, as John is last and has maximum amount, should not be printed. Why does it print? 2) I confused to use iter and *iter. Although I know basic concept of pointer and read a lot about that, I do not know when we should use iter or *iter in standard library. Please explain more for me.

Comment: You caught a mistake of mine, the answer has been edited. `std::vector::end()` does not point to the last element. Instead, it points to the one past it: `vector.back()+1`. Therefore, for every real element in the vector, it is true that `iter!=vector.end()`. It is undefined behavior to dereference `vector.end()`, the same idea as accessing an array out-of-bound.

Comment: For your second question, iterators can express: a position in a container (`begin()` is the first element's position), a range in a container when used in pair (`begin()` and `end()` together means the range of a whole `vector`), and the result of a search (the result of `find_if` and `max_element`, `iter == end()` represents no result found). When you are interested in the content of the element it points to, you should dereference it with `*iter` or `iter->` (iter->score and (*iter).score are equivalent).